# Create a data frame with numbers in each column

Tags: r

I have this simulation of 10000 random numbers

```
floor(runif(10000, 10,200))
```

but I need the data to be in following columns:

```
question_id choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4 correct_answer
(1-10000)    1       2       3       4         3
```

How can I obtain this using R `question_id` is ranges from 1 to 10000 and choices are repeated between 1 to 4 in respective columns & random correct answer between 1 to 4 choices in correct_answer column.

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted

Comment: Maybe `data.frame(question_id=sample(10000),choice1=1,choice2=2,choise3=3,choise4=4,correct_answer=sample(1:4,10000,T))` ? Not much clear for me either.

Comment: wat i hav done data.frame(list(candidate_id=c(1:10000),question_id=seq(1:10000),choice1=rep(1,10000),choice2=rep(2,10000),
                   choice3=rep(3,10000),choice4=rep(4,10000)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you need?

```
df  <- data.frame( question_id = seq(1:10000),choice1=1,choice2=2,choice3=3,choice4=4,correct_answer=sample(1:4,10000,T))

head(df)

  question_id choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4 correct_answer
1           1       1       2       3       4              1
2           2       1       2       3       4              3
3           3       1       2       3       4              2
4           4       1       2       3       4              1
5           5       1       2       3       4              1
6           6       1       2       3       4              2
```

Comment: Instead of `floor(runif(...))` use `sample`. See my comment.

Comment: yes. I kept it like OP's. but you do have a point of course. I'll edit accordingly